# Mongodb 1.5 and php 7.2 driver in xampp ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.7, php-7.2

Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

for this issue need to fix that we have to install php mongodb driver 
but i m not able to install . i have mongodb 1.5 and php 7.2 
and i m using in ubuntu and xampp 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

did you execute `sudo pecl install mongodb` after php and mongodb installation?

after this command you have to add the extension in php.ini `extension=mongodb.so`

Restart the apache

Comment: this command install default apache but i want  to install with xampp ububtu 16.04
Thanks

Comment: check this https://vitux.com/how-to-install-xampp-on-your-ubuntu-18-04-lts-system/